# Model classes and external libraries best practices

Tags: java, class, model, dependencies, libraries

I am developing a MVC rich GUI application in Java and I have to use an external scientific library which already defines most of the classes that I will potentially use in my domain model. What are the best practices in this case? may I need to wrap all the classes defined in the library with interfaces?

Comment: You mean the external library defines beans that you want to reuse in your application? Or GUI elements or...? What technology are you using for the GUI?

Comment: For GUI I am using JavaFX. and yes, I mean the external library defines beans that I want to reuse in my application.

Comment: I don't really see the problem then, just use the beans and cleanly separate the logic that binds the beans to the GUI elements.

Comment: From my perspective the problem is: this library mainly is an XML parser of a XML-based scientific standard. If the standard (and consequently the library) changes in near future I have my application stuck to the old standard. So I was thinking to wrap all of the classes with adequate interfaces, but still I don't know, generally speaking, if this is the most common approach to solve dependency on third party libraries.

Comment: If they update the standard, will your interfaces not be deprecated as well? Either the new features or removed features in the standard will have to be reflected in your interfaces I would assume.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would wrap 3rd party classes into implementation of my interface if:

- the 3rd party library is still evolving (new changes are expected)
- the 3rd party library is not solving all my issues
- I don't want to stick with only one provider (of the scientific library)
- my application is long term project

Otherwise I would us the 3rd party classes directly. Introducing unnecessary layers of abstraction at the beginning of the project is very often waste of time.